# How to mount multiple mirrors on a wall

Tags: mounting, mirror

I have eight 30x30cm mirrors that needed to be mounted side by side on a wall.
I tried different types of adhesives, but the result was not good, mainly because the wall is not smooth.

Are there any good ways to mount these mirrors on the wall?

I am thinking of using [Unframed Bathroom Mirror kits](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/711Bd8yv6FL._AC_SL1500_.jpg), but these apply to one huge mirror.

Comment: What kind of mirrors? Just bare panels? Most mirrors are hung with [steel clips](https://mobileimages.lowes.com/product/converted/008236/008236030259.jpg?size=pdhi) screwed to the wall framing. Is that not an option?

Comment: They are bare panels. The steel clips are not an option because I have eight mirrors that need to mounted as one big mirror, side-by-side.

Comment: That doesn't explain why they're not an option. Obviously the clips go on the top and bottom, so the arrangement isn't an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mount all you mirrors on a board or some other "smooth" substrate that will accept a good adhesive and then mount that to the wall. (*Or mount the board to the wall and then attach the mirrors*)

If you do not have a saw then you can have a home center cut a board to size for you.

You could have the board be larger then the overall dimensions of the mirrors and put a nice Frame around it.

Types  of substrates: Plywood, Particle board, Hardboard, OSB (Oriented strand Board)

Answer (score 3):

If you've ever watch a pro install mirror walls, they have a bucket of construction adhesive, made for mirrors, and they put a glob on each corner of the mirror and a glob in the center. They then place it on the wall and push. They will stick even if the wall isn't smooth and they can be adjusted if the wall is uneven. You'll need to support the bottom row with clips or a 1x2 fastened to the wall.